# Svelte: How to extract CSS in a specific file with rollup?

Tags: css, svelte, rollup, postcss

I would like to extract the style from `<style>` block in svelte components, and the included `css` files (e.g. `import 'datatables.net-bs4/css`) in a specific file.

I understand that this is the job of `rollup-plugin-postcss`, but I cannot achieve to make it work.

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss'
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

export default [{
      input: 'front/svelte/main.js',
      output: {
          sourcemap: true,
          format: 'iife',
          name: 'app',
          file: 'web/static/build/bundle.js'
     },
      plugins: [
        resolve({
            jsnext: true,
            main: true,
            browser: true,
        }),
        commonjs(),
        svelte({
            dev: !production,
            include: ['front/svelte/**', 'node_modules/svelte/**'],
        }),
        postcss({
            extract: true,
            minimize: true,
        }),
        !production && livereload('web'),
        production && terser()
      ],
    }
  }
];
```

I understood that the [extract](https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss#extract) option would generate a `web/static/build/bundle.css`, but nothing ever happens.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

By default the [svelte template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template/blob/e6e47d658ca61bf7bcb82d7424e5c2a3a21814ce/rollup.config.js#L48) uses the `rollup-plugin-css-only` plugin to do what you're looking for.

```js
// we'll extract any component CSS out into
// a separate file - better for performance
css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),
```

If possible, might be worth giving that a whirl to make sure a basic setup works, debug as necessary, and then see if you can switch back to `rollup-plugin-postcss`.